# Oscillating Spring & Rates of change

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

How to solve?

Are they asking for:

instantaneous rate of change: $\frac{d}{dt}h(t)=2.5$ and solve for value of $t$

or when $\frac{d}{dt}h(t_1)$ where $t_1$ is when $h(t)=2.5$

but both methods are leading me to strange answers.

the answers are out of:

$0.03 \\
-0.43 \\
-0.40 \\
-1.45 \\
1.67$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You are given that $t_1=2.5$. You need to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$ evaluated at $t_1$.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, take the derivative:
$$h'=0.5\left(0.05e^{-0.05t}\cos\left(\frac{3\pi t}{2}\right)+e^{-0.05t}\frac{3\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi t}{2}\right)\right)$$
Plug in:
h'=-1.45 seconds.